# Error: Package: python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 Requires: python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-64.el6 found: python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64

Tags: python, linux, bash, rhel

I am getting this error on running python setup.py for installing cffi python module.

```
c/cffi1_module.c: At top level:
c/cffi1_module.c:128: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
c/cffi1_module.c:150: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
c/_cffi_backend.c:6691: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘init_cffi_backend’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1, 

So this error on googling shows that I need to install python devel and on doing that I get the error below:

Error: Package: python-devel-2.6.6-64.el6.x86_64 (rhel-6-server-rpms)
           Requires: python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-64.el6
           Installed: python-libs-2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64 (@rhel6-patch-channel-may2015)
               python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-66.el6_8
```

According to the error- Requires: python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-64.el6 but installed is- python-libs(x86-64) = 2.6.6-66.el6_8, so how can I change it?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Check that the `cffi` module you downloaded is compatible with your version of python.

Answer (score 1):

Your `rhel-6-server-rpms` channel is not the official version.  The current `rhel-6-server-rpms` channel contents actually has Python at version 2.6.6-66.el6_8.x86_64, so the problem would not happen with it.  You need to look at `yum repolist -v` output and double-check that you are using the official repositories.  (You will need an active Red Hat Enterprise Linux subscription to access these repositories.)